# How can I obtain the commit logs prior to 11-13-15 for VS Code?

Tags: git, logging, visual-studio-code, commit

I am an intermediate C++ programmer and I am interested in forking VS Code. 
Since I am not very good at programming, it would really help if I had some of the very first commit logs available as a reference. Looking at the logs, however, I only see that they go back to 11-13-15, and that a huge amount of the VS Code code was already written(squashed) in that first available commit "Hello Code".

How can I obtain the logs prior to 11-13-15 for VS Code **?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic - it's not about programming, and the information you're looking for is probably simply not available anyway.

Comment: Commit logs aren't essential to programming???

Comment: Also, if there is no way to obtain VS Code's commit logs prior to 11-13-15 then THAT would be the answer, but a few people ought to confirm that though.

Comment: The question should be asked here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues. My guess is: they had been developing VS Code in another VCS; when at 11-13-15 they decided to open the source code to public they copied the existing code to a new git repository; so no logs existed before that.

Comment: @phd

  While a programmer can commit anything they tend to commit code. In other words commit logs **ARE** code, and that commited code is used as a guide to **how** to code for a particular codebase. They're also used as a point to branch from.

    The wiki says that only "bugs and feature requests" are permitted on github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues . If you really think my question belong there then I might just post there - I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, and what? Not to say that commit logs aren't code, they're just a history of the code.